# Htaccess with $_GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm really confused about something at the moment.
I'm trying to to make a page which uses the `$_Get` feature although, i'm also trying to clean it up in `.Htaccess`

I'm using the following, which works fine.

```
myurl.com/index.php?url=test&cat=2
```

Which .htaccess turns into

```
  myurl.com/test/2/
```

Although I am trying to add another variable on the end so it would be

```
myurl.com/test/2/3rdvariable/
```

My current .HTaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=test&cat=$1
```

I'd appreciate it, if anyone could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted this, I just found out my problem.

```
RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=test&cat=$1&cat=$2
```